# NullPointerException on bitmap.getPixels()

Tags: android, bitmap, nullpointerexception

Can someone help me? I keep getting this `NullPointerException` error.

```
03-23 22:50:43.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1978): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 22:50:43.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at         android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelsAccess(Bitmap.java:1365)
03-23 22:50:43.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at  android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixels(Bitmap.java:1310)
03-23 22:50:43.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at com.example.ocrtry.Entry2.downSample(Entry2.java:227)
03-23 22:50:43.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at com.example.ocrtry.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:42)
```

I tried putting a try and catch statement at downSample and i dont even get an output.
Here is the code for downSample

```
public void downSample()
{
  int w = bmInput.getWidth();
  int h = bmInput.getHeight();
  int[] pixels = null;
  bmInput.getPixels(pixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
  pixelMap = (int[])pixels;
  findBounds(w, h);

  SampleData data = sample.getData();

  ratioX = (double) (downSampleRight - downSampleLeft)
  / (double) data.getWidth();
  ratioY = (double) (downSampleBottom - downSampleTop)
  / (double) data.getHeight();

  for (int y = 0; y < data.getHeight(); y++)
  {
     for (int x = 0; x < data.getWidth(); x++)
     {
     if (downSampleQuadrant(x, y))
       data.setData(x, y, true);
     else
       data.setData(x, y, false);
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `downSample()` calls

```
bmInput.getPixels(pixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
```

with a null `pixels` array.

You need to allocate the array, and make it a suitable size.

```
int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
```

How you can debug a case like this: The stack trace shows the problem detected within `Bitmap.getPixels()` called from `downSample()`. That means the relevant line of your code is where it calls `getPixels()` (you can also tell by the line number `Entry2.java:227` in the stack trace). If `bmInput` was null it would throw a NPE trying to call a `getPixels()` method. (Actually, it would've thrown a NPE on the first line of the method, trying to call `bmInput.getWidth()`.) So `pixels` is the only remaining value that could be null. Then looking one line earlier in the code, it sets `bmInput` to null.